# Meaning of 'noted lights'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

;prominent individuals of both political parties, Society hostesses, well-known dramatic authors and novelists, and distinguished aeroplanists were dimly recognizable in that doomed throng; noted **lights** of the musical-comedy stage flickered wanly in the shades of the Inferno, smiling still from force of habit, but with the fearsome smiling rage of baffled effort.

The above 'lights' could be understood as 'A prominent or distinguished person; a luminary' as described in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation is correct. I find the quoted material very effective. It uses the term "noted lights" in the conventional metaphorial sense of those on the stage who are illuminated by the lights (and are therefore the objects of note and attention) but then re-illuminates them metaphorically with the light of the Inferno.